# C++ library comparison: Boost and Tr1

Tags: c++, boost, tr1

Which is more robust? Coz I read Linus Torvalds 's article about how bad is boost. Is that tr1 is better than boost?

Comment: You're taking C++ advice from Linus?

Comment: "Linus said it's bad" is a textbook fallacy of argument from authority, y'know. Could you cite that article? Perhaps it was this from 2007: http://lwn.net/Articles/249460/ ?

Comment: Linus says that C++ is bad, because he cannot find any good C++ programmers to work for him. Some of us believe this has nothing to do with the language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TR1 is a set of libraries that were proposed additions to the C++ Standard Library.  Most of them originated in Boost and most of them are now included in the latest C++0x draft standard.

There are some differences between different versions of the Boost implementations of the libraries, the TR1 specification of the libraries, and the latest C++0x specification, but the fundamentals are largely the same.

Linus Torvalds vocally hates C++ as a whole and his ranting about C++ should not be taken seriously.  The Boost libraries are extraordinarily useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make much sense, since Boost [*includes* the TR1 additions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_tr1.html), which in turn are mostly based on libraries that were born in Boost itself (the Boost implementation of TR1 can be seen somehow as an "informal reference implementation"); thus, I wouldn't know how to say "which is better", since it's all mostly the same.

By the way, I wouldn't listen too much to Linus Torvalds about these facts, he is quite biased against C++ in general, and almost anything he writes about it degenerates in generic rant.